# Express route in node JS invokes two routes

Tags: node.js, string, express, parameters, express-router

I have below kind of route in my project

```
router.get('/new', async function(req,res){
});

router.get('/:id', async function (req, res) {
});
```

when I invoked `/new` route from post-man, both the routes are executing. first the route `/new` gets executed and then the route with `/:id` also getting invoked. I dont knw understand why its getting confused and triggers both routes. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the route structure for both the endpoints are same. When you define a route `/:id`, it accepts some `X` value in the route. Now when you define your other as `/new` , express will consider `new` as the value of `X` and call that route too. Workaround for this is to change the structure of one of route. You should follow rest pattern to avoid such problems. You can read [here](https://www.toptal.com/nodejs/secure-rest-api-in-nodejs)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks understood now. So, each route should be a unique one, considering the route params.

Comment: Yes.. read about defining routes and rest standards, that will be useful.. glad my answer help :)